# Echo Value From Array Where

Tags: php, mysql

I'm probably going about this in completely the wrong way but I've got it half working!

I have a table (prices) which contains a 'pack' reference number and a 'price' for each pack.

I'm trying to echo different prices for each pack on the same page but seem to have got a bit lost!

eg. Pack 1 is £12 and pack 2 is £17. I'd like to be able to echo these values in different places on the same page.

Up to now I have...

```
 <?php 
    $con = mysql_connect('*****'); 
    mysql_select_db('****');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE pack=2";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    ?>
```

Then I have...

```
<?php echo $row['price'];}?>
```

further down the page where I want the price to appear.

This is fine if I only need the price for pack 2 on that page but if I want different prices on the same page it wont work.

I realise the WHERE pack=2 in the query is controlling the value echoed but I need to echo the price WHERE pack=1 and pack=2 on the same page.

Is there any way I can remove the WHERE from the query and have some kind of ECHO WHERE where I need the prices to appear on the page.

Hope this all makes sense and someone can point me in the right direction.

Cheers,
Bruce

Comment: i think you got only one record on same page in place of two records right ?

Comment: you can use `in` clause

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: Save prices in array, then echo those values where you need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using PDO, but you can do it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE pack=1 OR pack=2 ORDER BY pack ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$prices = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $prices[$row['pack']] = $row['price'];
}
```

Then, $prices[1] will contain price for pack=1, and $prices[2] will contain price for pack=2;

If you shall need more than packs 1 and 2, use IN clause:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE pack IN (1, 2, 5, 7) ORDER BY pack ASC";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the replies! This one works perfectly!
Thanks again, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should place price any where in page but inside while loop not outside while loop

```
<?php 
    $con = mysql_connect('*****'); 
    mysql_select_db('****');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE pack=2";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { ?>
          // place your HTML
         Price <input type="text" value="<?= $row['price'] ?>" />
   <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysqli_connect()` instead of older `mysql_connect()` as function is deprecated.

Try this way:-

```
 $link = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","db_name") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

 $query = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE pack IN ( 1,2 )"; 
 // If you want all pack prices then use below query
 // $query = "SELECT * FROM prices"; 

   //execute the query. 

 $result = $link->query($query); 

   //display information: 

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo $row['pack'] .'='. $row['price'] . "<br>"; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated my code to use the mysqli_connect as you suggested.